Group Travel Ticket Under 1 Reservation & A No-Show
I have a roundtrip group reservation for a group of 13 going to Mexico. What happens to the reservation if some people are a no-show with Southwest? Covid cases are on the rise in my area and I am worried that some may get sick and decide not to come. My concern is that the no-show(s) could cancel the entire reservation.

I assume you are referring to air travel, so I added the [tag:air-travel] tag.  Please [edit] your question if I was wrong.
